# What's the logic behind windows 10 taskbar highlight, and how to disable it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, taskbar

i wonder whats the logic behind windows taskbar hightlight, dont know why some app has 'active color' while others not . since i didnt open that application in front  of all application, and how to disable it or set color as normal?

[image: the orange 'highlight color' in taskbar]

Comment: The “logic” is that applications decide when they need attention. They also decide when they no longer need it.

Comment: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=10+taskbar+highlight%2C+and+how+to+disable+it%3F